# Is there a "more" command that can be used in the Git shell in windows?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-shell

The git shell has a few useful commands that aren't part of windows usual cmd (`ls`,`git grep`).

Is there a command like *nix's

```
more filename.ext
```

available in the git shell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have MSys Git v1.8.5.2. It has `less` command. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/310137/less-is-more-is-more-less-im-so-confused) is good article about both of them.